# Como puedo transformar la funcion WEEK() de MySQL hacia LINQ

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-6

alguien puede ayudarme a resolver mi siguiente problema. Necesito convertir una consulta MySQL que contiene la función WEEK() hacia Lambda para usarlo con C# y Entity Framework 6.

Mi consulta en MySQL:

```
DateTime fecha = DateTime.Now;
string semana = WeeksInYear(fecha).ToString(); //First day of week = Monday, Range: 1-53
select * from tSemanal where WEEK(FechaSemanal,3) = " + semana + " and YEAR(FechaSemanal) = " + fecha.Year
```

He probado con varias recomendaciones que encontré en la web, pero ninguna funciona, esto fue lo ultimo que probe y nada.

```
using (var DbContext = new dbEntities())
{
   var query = DbContext.tSemanal
            .Where(x => x.FechaSemanal.Date.DayOfYear / 7 == semana)                                
            .SingleOrDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

lo que puede estar pasando es que al decir  FechaSemanal.Date.DayOfYear / 7 usted esta haciendo una división de enteros, con lo cual se perderán todos los decimales. cuando usted debe redondear hacia arriba, por favor intente con:

```
var query = DbContext.tSemanal
            .Where(x => (int)Math.Ceiling(x.FechaSemanal.Date.DayOfYear/7.0) == semana)                                
            .SingleOrDefault();
```